# CCleaner Driver Wiper completely removed Bitlocker property

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, bitlocker, ccleaner

I use a Bitlocker drive with my Win7-64 Ultimate. So just to get rid of data in there, I wanted to use CCleaner Driver Wiper feature. I selected "erase drive" instead of free space wiping. And next thing I see this bitlocker drive became a standart drive. Bitlocker status is gone and I had to re-enable bitlocker with a password etc.

Is this the way it should be? 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you "erase drive"?

Comment: Yes?  **You told CCleaner to wipe the drive.** What did you think would happen?

Comment: I didn't think I'd have to turn on bitlocker again. So if I format the drive with builtin format tool, do I have to turn bitlocker on again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source [Where are the encryption keys stored?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449438%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_KeyStorage)

> Where are the encryption keys stored?
>
> **The full volume encryption key is encrypted by the volume master key
>   and stored in the encrypted drive**. The volume master key is encrypted
>   by the appropriate key protector and stored in the encrypted drive. If
>   BitLocker has been suspended, the clear key that is used to encrypt
>   the volume master key is also stored in the encrypted drive, along
>   with the encrypted volume master key.
>
> This storage process ensures that the volume master key is never
>   stored unencrypted and is protected unless you disable BitLocker. The
>   keys are also saved to two additional locations on the drive for
>   redundancy. The keys can be read and processed by the boot manager.

So if you wipe the drive you lose both the encryption keys as well as all data that was on the drive.